# Adjusting results based on its probability

Tags: probability

Given that the chance of event A occur is `10 in 25` and event B is `15 in 25`.

Checking the field data I've got the result below:

A occured `124` times and B occured `215` times.

So how can I '*adjust*' the distortion of A in relation to B since B is more probable?

I've tried to find the occurence factor based on its probability:

$$
C_A=\frac{\left(\frac{124}{124+215}\right)}{\left(\frac{10}{25}\right)} \text{ and }  C_B=\frac{\left(\frac{215}{124+215}\right)}{\left(\frac{15}{25}\right)}
$$

But the results don't sum up to 2 (?)

$ C_A=0,91$ and, $C_B = 1,06$ so $ C_{A+B}=1,97$

I've poor math skills so any direction is welcome.

Comment: This sounds more like a statistics question, and so you could flag it to be migrated to stats.stackexchange.com. However, I think more information is needed. What are you trying to learn by 'adjusting' the results? Why should they sum up to 2?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala if Event A should occur in 40% and B in 60%, I want to check the deviation on the results. So a result of $C_A = 1$ means that A occured exactly on 40% as expected, and so for B. So adding up A and B should give me 2 or 2x100%.

Answer (score 1):

@Paulo Bueno

One reason you are so far off is that your sample size is so small ( only 339 ). When I do 1000000 I get

$\frac{C_a}{\left(C_a+C_b\right) 0.4}+\frac{C_b}{\left(C_a+C_b\right) \
0.6}=1.99998$

which is much closer.

Looks like the larger the simulation the closer to 2 you get, which is as expected. As a matter of fact an answer of 2 is impossible with 339.

Proof:

$$C_a+C_b=339 \\
\frac{\frac{C_a}{C_a+Cb}}{.4}+\frac{\frac{C_b}{C_a+Cb}}{.6}=2$$

$$C_a=135.6$$

$$C_b=203.4$$
which is obviously impossible.